# Filter realm results with variable id using RxSwift

Tags: realm, rx-swift

I want to use `Variable` in Rxswift to make caseResults search different Results with different boxId, like `boxId == 1` get Results and `boxId == 2` get another Results

```
class MainViewModel {

    let cases: Driver<[CaseItemViewModel]>
    let index = Variable<Int>(1)

    init() {
        let caseResults = realm.objects(RMCase.self)
                            .filter("boxId == \(index.value)")
                            .sorted(byKeyPath: "id", ascending: true)


        self.cases = Observable.collection(from: caseResults)
            .asDriverOnErrorJustComplete()
            .map { results in results.map { CaseItemViewModel(with: $0) }}
    }
}


class CaseItemViewModel {
    let cased: RMCase
    let id: Int
    let boxId: Int
    let name: String

    init(with cased: RMCase) {
        self.cased = cased
        self.id = cased.id
        self.boxId = cased.boxId
        self.name = cased.name
    }
}
```

In the ViewController

```
    viewModel.boxs
        .drive(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: CellId.main.rawValue, cellType: MainTableViewCell.self)) { [weak self] row, item, cell in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            cell.setup(with: item)

            // drive collectionView into tableViewCell
            if let collectionView = cell.collectionView {

                strongSelf.viewModel.cases.asObservable()
                    .bind(to:collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "testcell", cellType: MainCollectionViewCell.self)) { _row, _item, _cell in

                     _cell.setup(with: _item)
                    }
                    .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
            }

            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Variable` is deprecated, use `BehaviorRelay` or `BehaviorSubject` instead.

Change `cases` to `BehaviorRelay` so you don't have to initialise it in `init` and then observe `index` property and everytime it changes, bind new result to `cases` like this:

```
let cases = BehaviorRelay<[CaseItemViewModel]>(value: [])
let index = BehaviorRelay<Int>(value: 1)

init() {
  index
    .flatMap { index -> Observable<Results<RMCase>> in
      let caseResult = realm.objects(RMCase.self)
                            .filter("boxId == \(index)")
                            .sorted(byKeyPath: "id", ascending: true)

      return Observable.collection(from: caseResult)
    }
    .map { results in results.map { CaseItemViewModel(with: $0) }}
    .bind(to: cases)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

In `cases` you now always have array of `CaseItemViewModel` and it will be filled with new values everytime `index` changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it's still display the index with   the initial value

Comment: @廖豪豪 I don't really understand you. When you call `index.value = 0` the `cases` array still contains values for index 1?

Comment: You mean `let index = BehaviorRelay<Int>(value: 0)`?It will get empty `cases`

Comment: @廖豪豪 Well, then probably you have no `RMCase` with `boxID == 0`.

Comment: I add my RMCase photo , the first id is `1`(sry, I uploaded at wrong position)

Comment: @廖豪豪 Yes.. so if you set `let index = BehaviorRelay<Int>(value: 2)` or call `index.accept(2)` you will get results for `boxID == 2` - 2 values. Is there any problem?

Comment: When I called `let index = BehaviorRelay<Int>(value: 2)`, both displayed the `boxId ==2` column's data

Comment: @廖豪豪 I'm really sorry but I don't understand what is a problem now.

Comment: This` collectionView` is inside` tableViewCell` , so when I called `BehaviorRelay<Int>(value: 2)`, and every `tableViewCell's collectionView` are get the column of 3 and 4 information, but I want the first tableViewCell is driven by `boxId ==1` and the secondis driven by `boxId ==2`

Comment: I added ViewController code, please help me solve this issue, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167476/discussion-between-kiwisip-and-).